# Beamer: Onslide with hyperlink to end of slide drops bottom colorbox

Tags: beamer

I defined a beamer template that puts a color box as the bottom of each slide. In a main slide, I make phrases gradually appear using `\onslide`. On the same slide, I put a hyperlink at the end of the slide to go to a slide in the appendix. From the appendix, I use a hyperlink to go back to the main slide. To make sure that I go back to the end of the slide, not the beginning, I use `\hypertarget` in the main slide.

The problem: With this setup, the colorbox on the bottom is not visible until the item with the hypertarget is displayed. But I want the bottom line to be visible all the time.

Using `\itemize[<+->]` is not an option since I sometimes want to pair several points to appear at once. I experimented with other hyperlinks, but they did not get me back to the end of the main slide from the appendix. I tried to use `\pause`, but that didn't work either.

How can I do a gradual overlay, use a hyperlink that gets me back to the end of the slide and keep my colorbox visible all the time?

Here's a MSW:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]
{author in head/foot}%
            %\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
            Institution
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]
{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Main slide}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \onslide<2->{
    \item Item 2}
        \onslide<3->{
            \item Item 3 \hypertarget<3>{main}} 
    \end{itemize}
\vspace{1cm}
\hyperlink{appendix}{\beamergotobutton{Appendix}}
 \end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Appendix slide} %Slide10
\label{appendix}
   Appendix slide
    \hyperlink{main}{\beamerreturnbutton{Main slide}}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem: `\hypertarget` takes two arguments, one for the name and one for text. You can leave the text empty, but you cannot not give it.

The construct with wrapping the items in `\onslide<2->{...}` seems very complicate, I suggest to either let beamer do the uncovering for you (`\begin{itemize}[<+->]`) or if you need more fine control use overlay argument of the items (`\item<3-> text`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]
    {author in head/foot}%
            %\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
            Institution
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]
    {date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
    }


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Main slide}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3\hypertarget<3>{main}{} 
\end{itemize}

\hyperlink{appendix}{\beamergotobutton{Appendix}}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[label=appendix]{Appendix slide} %Slide10
    Appendix slide
  \hyperlink{main}{\beamerreturnbutton{Main slide}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```